# Cannot execute Python3 script via escapeshellcmd or shell_exec

Tags: php, python-3.x

I have a PHP script in which I want to send some data to Python3 to perform some clustering analysis of the data. For smaller amount of data, I want to directly escape the data via shell:

```
$result = shell_exec('python3 /var/www/testsite/py/script.py 2>&1 $jsondata')
```

For larger amount of data, I want to read json data into python3 and write the results to an output file:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /var/www/testsite/py/script2.py 2>&1');
exec($command)
```

The code worked on a virtual server running on my laptop with the old php 5 version and Python3, but on Apache2 server with PHP 7.4.3 and Python3 I cannot execute the python scripts via PHP.

However, if I run the command via shell on the server, reading the input data, processing it and storing it in an output file works perfectly fine:

```
python3 /var/www/testsite/py/script.py 2>&1
```

same as

```
/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/testsite/py/script.py 2>&1
```

The python script looks like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys, json
import scipy
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib


# Load the data from json file
try:
  with open('/var/www/testsite/files/inputfile.json', 'r') as inputfile:
  data = json.load(inputfile, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict) 
except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError, KeyError) as e:
  print (json.dumps({'error': str(e)}))
  sys.exit(1)

#############################
  Some data processing here
#############################

# Write processed data to json outputfile
with open('/var/www/testsite/files/outputfile.json', 'w') as outputfile:
json.dump(processed_data, outputfile)
```

I tried a number of things to solve this, like adding the complete path-to-python3 to the PHP command:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/testsite/py/script.py 2>&1 $jsondata')
```

or adding the shebang line at the top of my python scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Both without success. I gave permissions for reading and writing to python scripts and input/output json files, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

**Edit:** I can see the following error in the error.log,

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'
```

which is strange since I don't get the error when executing the python script via command line. Numpy version installed is 1.21.0.

**Edit2:** I created a python script version that I call from PHP via escapeshellcmd/exec(), which just reads the json data, and writes it to an output file without further data processing:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys, json


# Load the data from json file
try:
   with open('/var/www/testsite/files/inputfile.json', 'r') as inputfile:
      data = json.load(inputfile, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict) 
   except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError, KeyError) as e:
      print (json.dumps({'error': str(e)}))
   sys.exit(1)


# write data to json outputfile
with open('/var/www/testsite/files/outputfile.json', 'w') as outputfile:
json.dump(data, outputfile)
```

The output file can successfully be written, which means that there must be some loading error with one or more of the packages required for data processing. I am directly loading the following packages in addition to the ones above:

```
import scipy
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
```

This is the complete error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/testsite/py/hclust_esc.py", line 4, in <module>
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import vq, hierarchy
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 74, in <module>
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
from .kdtree import *
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 8, in <module>
import scipy.sparse
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
from .base import *
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 8, in <module>
from .sputils import (isdense, isscalarlike, isintlike,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py", line 16, in <module>
supported_dtypes = [np.typeDict[x] for x in supported_dtypes]
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
supported_dtypes = [np.typeDict[x] for x in supported_dtypes]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 320, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'
```

Comment: What exactly does "cannot" mean? Do you get errors? Status codes? _Anything_?

Comment: Do you happen the have some file named `numpy.py` or something yourself in your working directory?

Comment: No, nothing with this name or a name similar to a package

Comment: Do you have a more extensive error log?

Comment: Do you try to pass `$jsondata` from PHP here: `'python3 .../script.py 2>&1 $jsondata'`? Because `$jsondata` will be literal string because of single quotes

Comment: Yes, and I read this in python3 by "json.load(inputfile...)"